# what happens with commanders and o ring effects?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I know that when a commander is exiled, the owner has the option of putting it in 
exile or back in the command zone, but what about effects that only remove it as 
long as a permanent is in play, like o ring, or angel of serenity. does the 
commander leave play until the mentioned permanents leave play or can the opp bypass them and just put the commander in the command zone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as rule 903.9 describes, the commander's owner may put it in the command zone:

> If a commander would be exiled from anywhere or put into its owner’s hand, graveyard, or library from anywhere, its owner may put it into the command zone instead